# How do I get an element id text changes?

Tags: selenium, testing, appium

I have an element text always changes except time format: Ex:

`"jorday hekci 4:35pm hello"`

`"read message 12:05am jack"`

`"read message 2:35am test"`

`"I love stackoverflow 4:59pm everytime"`

I tried this way and  still does not work.

```
 @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new 
    UiSelector().className(\"android.Widget.Text\").textMatches(\"((1[0-2]|0?[0-9]):([0-5][0-9]) 
    ([ap][m]))\")
    MobileElement Element; 


<android.view.View resource-id="exp-rodeo-11">
<android.view.View resource-id="exp-rodeo-12">
<android.view.View resource-id="exp-element-111">
<android.view.View resource-id="exp-element-222">
<android.Widget.Text>
```

xpath = xpath
 /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View

Comment: Please add the html of the element

Comment: why dont you use one of the attributes (like content-desc, xpath)? this is the ugliest pattern to use regex to match text field

Comment: will be helpful if you can share xml structure of elements.